# Scanf won't assign the user inputed value to a variable | C

Tags: c

When scanf is used to get the second integer for the calculation, it assigns 0 to sec instead of the user inputed value. Please Help!

```
// This program will act as a basic calculator`enter code here`
// The user will input two numbers and an operand. The program will print
// the result of the operation

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int first; //Variable for the first input of the user
    int sec;   //Variable for the second input of the user
    char operand[1]; //Variable for the operand inputed by the user
    int op, answer; //Dummy Variables for temp use
    printf("This is a simple calculator. Make sure you don't divide by 0!!\n");
    printf("Enter your first integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &first); //Ask the user to input the first number for the     calculation
    printf("\nEnter your second integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &sec); //Ask the user to input the second number for the calculation
    printf("Enter the operand.\n");
    scanf("%s", operand); //Ask the user to input the operand of the     calculation (+,-,*,/)
    printf("%i %s %i\n", first, operand, sec); //Display the calculaiton to be made
    op = (int) operand[0]; // converts the operand to an ASCII value
}
```

Comment: What did you type in?

Comment: Also, `operand` is too small, so you experience a buffer overrun.

Comment: If `operand` is a single char (as suggested by the cast on the last line), make it a char and read it with `%c`.

Comment: Did you print `sec` right after reading it? Without first reading `operand`?

Comment: Always check the result of `scanf`.

Comment: `char operand[1];` --> `char operand[100];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char operand[1]; //Variable for the operand inputed by the user
```

C uses null-terminated strings. That means that the smallest possible string ("") will consist just of 1 character: `0x00`.

When you're trying to read something like "+" from the input, that's a string consisting of two bytes: `0x2B 0x00`. As memory is allocated only for a single character (`operand[1]`), `0x2B` goes here, and the terminating null `0x00` accidentally goes to the `sec` variable.

This is called [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). In your case, the solution is to allocate more space for the string, or to use just a single character.

Comment: No, it is called _undefined behaviour_. And where the second entry is stored is not defined. The compiler is free to place operands at will (e.g. CPU registers, non-overlapping usage might re-use the same storage, etc.) as long the code stays correct (presuming the source code is correct, of course).

Comment: *Buffer overflow* results in *undefined behaviour*, isn't it? I've just explained the underlying magic to make it easy to understand what is happening there.

Comment: No. Accesssing an array beyond its bounds **is** undefined behaviour. Prepare for [nasal daemons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). There is no practical use in further investigating what will/might/could have happen(ed). And the "underlying magic" cannot be explained, as it can (and likely will) change with compiler, settings, target, OS, etc. Note that your claim is very likely wrong, as the array will be padded to have the following variable aligned (presuming it actually is placed "after" the array on the stack).

Comment: Subtle detail: When you're trying to read something like "+" from the input, that's _results in_ a string consisting of two bytes: `0x2B 0x00`. The null character is not read from the user. The function `scanf()` appends one to the character array `operand[]` making is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32685685/1983495) which is correct in the sense that it addresses the actual problem, you may want to instruct `scanf()` to scan just a single character, like this

```
scanf(" %c", operand);
/*     ^ this is needed with the %c specifier in order to skip spaces */
```

but then you have to be careful when using `operand` because it's not a string, it's an array of just one character, and using it like this

```
printf("%i %s %i\n", first, operand, sec);
```

would invoke *undefined behavior* because `printf()` will try to read past the end of the `operand` array.

You can do it like this too,

```
char operand;

scanf(" %c", &operand);
/*     ^ this is needed with the %c specifier in order to skip spaces */
```

in this case the `printf()` would change to

```
printf("%d %c %d\n", first, operand, sec);
/*       ^ is normally used instead of %i, though %i is correct */
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed operand to a single character and the program works! Thank you for your help

Comment: Please add the corrected (hopefully correct) code to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

the variable: `operand` is only 1 byte long.

However, when inputting via %s using scanf(),

scanf will always append a NUL byte.

So the code performs some undefined behaviour which can result in anything,  including a seg fault event

this line:

```
op = (int) operand[0]; // converts the operand to an ASCII value
```

does not convert the 'operand' to an ascii value,  it was already a ascii value (I.E + - / * etc )

What it actually does is convert char 'operand' to int 'op'